# Getting the full Path of a Files, when you only have a part of the name of the file stored in a String [ ]

Tags: c#

I've stored in a "String []", the ID of the files that I need to move to another folder.

All Files has different Prefix, and there are hundreds of files.

[image: All Files has different Prefix]

What I want to do is get the Full Path of the files containing the "ID" in order to be able to move it in another folder.

What's the problem ?

I'm not able to get the Full Path of the file with only a piece of the name files.
Any kind of help, would be much appreciated.

```
        string ID = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\zig.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(ID);
        Console.ReadLine();


        String root = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\tiptop\";
        String[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\zig.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(root,(lines[i-1]));

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("" + fullPath);
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Length;i++)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("" + lines[i]);
            string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\tiptop\");

            Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\tiptop\", lines[i]));
```

Comment: Why not? if you only have 3 places you look for them, loop through the files, check each place.. tada?

Comment: Do you mean to search for all files with the "id"? Try using a wildcard and loop through the possible directories to match for the files

Answer (score 0):

We can scan the files and match them with `Ids` with a help of *Linq*:

```
  // HashSet<string> is faster for Contains then string[]: O(1) vs. O(N)
  HashSet<string> Ids = new HashSet<string>() {
    "011911772",
    "123456789",
  };

  string[] dirsToScan = new string[] {
    @"c:\Utilisateurs",
    @"d:\MyFiles",
    @"c:\SomeOtherDir\SomeFolder",
  };

  var regex = new Regex("[0-9]+$"); 

  //TODO: check search options (and restrict if possible)
  var files = dirsToScan
    .SelectMany(dir => Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    .Where(file => {
      var match = regex.Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));

      return match.Success && Ids.Contains(match.Value);
    })
    .ToArray(); // Let's materialize as an array
```